# Explicit interface declaration error on AAR binding MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I am trying to bind android aar library to use on MAUI/Xamarin. When I build the project I see the following error message.

```
CS0538  'IAsyncResponseReturn' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface
```

Here is the method throwing the above error

```
// This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Esewa.Android.Sdk.Payment.IAsyncResponseReturn
        void global::Com.Esewa.Android.Sdk.Payment.IAsyncResponseReturn.OnTaskFinished (global::Java.Lang.Object? p0)
        {
            OnTaskFinished (p0?.ToString ());
        }
```

Error List:
[image]

Can anyone help me to add metadata to resolve this issue?

Comment: From the log you posted above, we can find an attempt was made to explicitly declare an interface, but an interface was not specified. For more information, check: [Compiler Error CS0538](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0538).